# need help calculating answer to have decimals in c++

Tags: c++, decimal

i cant get this code to have a decimal in the final answer however i do get the correct answer not sure what to do at this point please help

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

   int n1,n2,n3,n4,n5;

   printf("Please enter the cost of the car then your down payment\n");


   scanf("%d%d",&n1,&n2);
   n3=n1-n2;

   printf("Now enter how many months of financing you would like\n");
   scanf("%d",&n4);

   n5=n3*1.05/n4;
   printf("Your car payment is %d per month",n5);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look up what values `int` stores and `%d` prints. Moreover, doing this: `int n1,n2,n3,n4,n5;` is bad on a number of levels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems.

1. Main problem is that you are losing precision in the line:

   ```
   n5=n3*1.05/n4;
   ```

   Use a floating point type for `n5` to avoid losing precision.

   ```
   double n5 = n3*1.05/n4;
   ```
2. Change the `printf` line to print the floating point type with 2 digits after the decimal point.

   ```
   printf("Your car payment is %.2f per month\n", n5);
   ```

Comment: thanks that worked for me i had tried using floats and doubles for n5 but my answer always came out to 0 but the %f fixed that thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You won't get decimals when only working with integers. You'd need to use floating point types like `double` or `float`.